# Android Icon / Bitmap color

Tags: android, xamarin, maui

I am trying to build a notification saver. I want to save the icon of a notification to restore it later on.
I use .NET Maui / Xamarin, but the code is very similar to Java, so you should be able to understand.

This is my code to save the image to disk:

```
    public override void OnNotificationPosted(StatusBarNotification? sbn)
    {
            var icon = Icon.CreateWithResource(sbn.Notification.SmallIcon.ResPackage, sbn.Notification.SmallIcon.ResId);
            var resources = Application.Context.PackageManager.GetResourcesForApplication(sbn.Notification.SmallIcon.ResPackage);
            var bitmap = BitmapFactory.DecodeResource(resources, icon.ResId);

            var bytes = bitmap.AsImageBytes(Bitmap.CompressFormat.Png);
            var path = $"/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/{Application.Context.PackageName}/test.png";
            var filestream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create);
            bitmap.Compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.Png, 100, filestream);
            filestream.Close();
    }
```

The image is saved, however it is white. As an example the result of a whatsapp message:

[image]

It is white with a transparent background. Thats why it appears to be invisible here. Normally, the whatsapp icon is green. I cant find any property or method that would change the color, neither from the Bitmap, Icon or Drawable. Any idea how I can get the colors?
Also, only most of the images are white. Some, e.g. TikTok or Xing are colored.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Not really understand the "how to get the color", if the image you are saving is white then by looking at your code it is white. Now if the third-party software is tinting it itsself you should do the same if needed.

Comment: According to the code you posted, I think the image should be saved as it was if you didn't change the image.

Comment: I am not sure what you guys mean. The image in the notification is not white, so I want to save it in the color that is used in the notification.